# Is there any open source video editing plugin for PHP?

Tags: open-source, video, php

I am developing a PHP based application which has a module called 'video wizard'. By using the video wizard, the user can create/upload videos and modify it by adding text. Let me know if is there any plugin/or open source code available for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want PHP to do the processing in your backend, PHP should merely dispatch the task and link resources.

With that in mind, try out the [FFmpeg PHP driver](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) and have it call [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), which is made for this.  From there, you'll be able to do pretty much anything ffmpeg does.

Related:

[StackOverflow - Adding text to video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg)